# Disable color in shell/terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, colors

I want to disable all color in my shell.  Not ls, not nano, not vi, nothing.  What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you are using PUTTY to remotely access the shell, then:
- on the left panel, click Colors

- uncheck the three boxes on the right panel (they are checked by default)

Comment: I'll have to switch to a terminal program that lets me do this.  Thanks.

Comment: Geekosaur's answer is better for you, really.

Comment: @slomojo his answer didn't work with my terminal client

Comment: Oh, interesting, which client is it?

Comment: I'm using iTerm (OS X) and still getting color if I export TERM=vt220, and in 'ls' even after unsetting LS_COLORS

Comment: Same thing for me using Putty from Windows XP into a Centos 5.5 system. In other words, the ls command still gives colors after unsetting LS_COLORS.<br />Poe, if my answer works for you, please choose it as the answer.

Comment: Also, if you have Putty already open in a session, you can click on the window menu (on the top left corner) to bring the 'right panel'. Click on Settings... and then Colors

Answer (score 14):

`unset LS_COLORS; export TERM=xterm` should do it, or at least get you most of the way there.  You may need to change that to say `TERM=vt220` for some overly "smart" programs.

Comment: Definitely recommend VT220 over XTERM.

Comment: "xterm" is a color terminal, to disable colors you need TERM=xterm-mono

Answer (score 7):

```
xterm -cm
```

This will start an xterm with no colors.

Comment: This won't work if you have LS_COLORS set FYI.

Comment: This is the best answer.  Also, @lzap appears to be incorrect, at least on Ubuntu.  xterm -cm give me a no-color terminal on Ubuntu regardless of LS_COLORS.

Comment: Well I meant that it will break terminal on Red Hat systems with LS_COLORS set by default.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem while writing an SSH robot in Python (colors came out as jibberish when run through Visual Studio). The simplest solution was to open a new shell inside the other shell that was running.

```
sh
```

This opened a fresh shell without any of my settings and all printouts was monochrome. It also reset the prompt which was a bonus for my intended purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is probably to tell your terminal emulator and environment that it cannot support colors in the first place:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bashrc
unset LS_COLORS
TERM=xterm-mono
export TERM
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

make a backup of .bashrc and then open .bashrc and remove all of these lines. this has the added benefit of disabling text colors in gedit!

```sh
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm|xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\] '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\] '
    fi
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w \$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi
```